# How can I load specific data from an external server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to create a variable with the text from `div#title`, which is located on a different, external server (i.e. not my website).

The domain has the following HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper>
        <div id="title>Title Text Here</div>
        <!-- LOTS MORE HTML HERE -->
    </div>
</body>
```

I am currently loading the data from the server using an HTTP GET request:

```
baseURL = "http://foowebsite.com"
$.get(baseURL, function(data){
    var title = $("#title", data).text();
}, "html");
```

But since the external domain has significant HTML below `div#title`, approximately five seconds pass before I can use the variable. Is there a quicker, more efficient way to get the text from `div#title`?

For example, can I make the GET request stop after it loads the `#title` div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do to make the external site load faster (unless you own it) - if it takes 5 seconds to load, then it takes 5 seconds to load.

Comment: But could I, for example, make the GET request stop after it loads the `#title` div?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: not with `jQuery` ajax methods, and maybe not with anything else either, depending on whether 1) the site sends `transfer-encoding: chunked` and 2) it's actually sends chunks in addition to sending the header.